# git cherry-picked commit, but files whole replaced, how can I recalculate difference?

Tags: git, merge, cherry-pick

I made cherry-pick of a commit from the feature branch to the master branch.
But these changed files was moved to another folder in master-branch.
So I have used follow answer to merge moved files:
[git merge conflict due to moved files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904653/git-merge-conflict-due-to-moved-files)

But now I have a problem:
instead of calculate the diff of replaced files git want to override them all.
How can I recalculate difference for a correct merge-commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in

#### Some files have incorrect encodings or file-endings

It could be solved by next way:

```
# undo incorrect merge commit, if it is made 
$ git reset --soft <commit>
# hide changes
$ git stash
# change encodings or endings in your text editor
$ vim file
:set fileencoding=utf-8
:set ff=dos
:wq
# create commit
$ git commit -m "enc"
# apply merge
$ git stash apply
$ git commit -m "merge"
```